# Unable to fetch data in my shiny app from Postgres SQL after publishing on shinyapps.io server

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, publishing, shinyapps

My shiny app works fine on my local machine and is able to fetch data from 
Postrges SQL and display in the tableoutput but once I publish it on shinyapps.io server then the data is lost.Below is the code. Can anyone guide me what is wrong with the code.

```
library(dbplyr)
library(RPostgres)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(lubridate)
library(rsconnect)
library(DT)
library(pool)


pool <- dbPool(

drv = Postgres(),

dbname = "xyz",
host = "a.b.c.com",
port = "5432",
user = "xxxx",
sslmode = "require",
password = "xxxxx"
)

header <- dashboardHeader(
title = 'TEST'
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(

div(style ="font-family: sans-serif",
  boxPlus(DT::DTOutput("table_1"),
          id = 'body_box',
          width = 'auto', status = "success",
          label_status = "danger"))

  )

   # Put them together into a dashboardPage
   ui <- dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body, skin = "black")

   server <- function(input,output,session){



  deal_hdr <- pool %>% tbl(in_schema('canada', 'deal_done')) %>%
   select(a, b, c, d) %>%
  head(10000)

 data_react <- data.frame(deal_hdr) 

  output$table_1 <- DT::renderDT(datatable(data_react,
                                       extensions = 
                          c('FixedColumns','KeyTable'), 
                                       rownames = FALSE,
                                       options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                                                      scrollY = TRUE,
                                                      fixedColumns = 
TRUE,
                                                      keys = TRUE)))
 }

 shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Below is the error that I got while publishing the app :

```
   Error in value[[3L]](cond) : could not translate host name "a.b.c.com" to 
   address: Name or service not known Calls: local ... tryCatch -> 
   tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous> Execution halted
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a problem in the connection to the database server?

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva what do you mean by problem ?

Comment: Maybe the shinyapps server doesn't have route to the host of your Postrges server.

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva how to make sure that shinyapps server is route to my Postgres server ?

Comment: You can debug the app, print some output to know where have your program passed. If it got stuck in some point or the error code of the connection code.

Comment: Maybe it's a scoping issue. Try `pool <<- dbPool(`.

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva  Below is the error that I got while publishing the app :                                                                                                        
  Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  could not translate host name "a.b.c.com" to address: Name or service not known
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted